# Opening a simple dialog in Pyside

Tags: python, pyside, signals-slots

My problem is simple yet i am blind to the solution. All i wish to do is to open 
a simple dialog when the corresponding menu button or sub section is clicked.
And doing so while using the new,newer syntax for connecting.
This is the small, short simple code.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

import TheMainWindow
import PutnickiVozDialog


class TheApp(QMainWindow, TheMainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TheApp,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.actionDodaj_Novi.connect(self.openNewPutnicki)


    def openNewPutnicki(self):
        self.putDialog = QDialog(self)
        self.putUi = PutnickiVozDialog.Ui_putnickiSearchDialog()
        self.putUi.setupUi(self.putDialog)
        self.putDialog.show()


theApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
theWindow = TheApp()
theWindow.show()
theApp.exec_()
```

I have done so following tutorials. But i get the following error report. And i do not know what is it that i am missing.

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Projects/Xml Database Project/PyCharm Workspace/TheApplication.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Projects/Xml Database Project/PyCharm Workspace/TheApplication.py", line 45, in <module>
    theWindow = TheApp()
  File "C:/Projects/Xml Database Project/PyCharm Workspace/TheApplication.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.actionDodaj_Novi.connect(self.openNewPutnicki)
TypeError: PySide.QtCore.QObject.connect(): not enough arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am sorry if i'm blind to something really simple here. But it just won't work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `self.actionDodaj_Novi.triggered.connect(self.openNewPutnicki)`.